# Why use /24 instead of /16 when creating new networks?

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I'm experimenting with setting up VPNs with Wireguard. It seems to work well, but I noticed most of the examples online suggest using something like `10.0.0.0/24` as the ip range for your wireguard network. If I understand correctly, that means you can only have a maximum of 254 nodes in the VPN (10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.254).

My question is... is there any reason to limit yourself like this? Seems like choosing `/24` only limits you as your network scales up. Why not do `10.0.0.0/16` out of the gate so you have 65000+ peers that can be in your VPN?

Comment: What research have you done regarding reasons to limit the number of available/possible IPs in a network? I would guess there is a lot of information online regarding this.

Comment: Your individual needs would determine if 10.0.0.0/24 or 10.0.0.0/16 should be used. The answer to the your question would be entirely based on your business needs.  Do you have a need for more than 254 devices connected to your VPN?

Comment: So much more conflict potential with local networks. Why do you believe you’ll have more than 254 hosts on the VPN subnet directly? Remember routing is still a thing.

Comment: @music2myear - mainly because I wasn't using the right terms for search engines until I read your comment. Searching "reasons to limit subnet size" has been very helpful!

Comment: @Ramhound - I do not have a need for more than 254 at the moment. But I'm just imagining that years from now, the number of users of my VPN might exceed 254 and I'm just wondering why I shouldn't future proof it now vs. have a headache later when I run out of ip addresses.

Comment: @Gillespie - It takes a simple restart of the service to expand your VPN subnet.

Comment: One note to save you a lot of pain in future. do NOT use 10.0.0.0 as your netork. instead use somthing like 10.241.143.0/24, 10.111.0.0/16 or somthing like that. you CANNOT connect two networks with the same IP range together with a VPN (unless you get into serious enterprise solutions), so avoid commonly used networks like 10.0.0.0, 172.16.0.0/16, 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.254.0/24. if you avoid those you drop the possibility of conflict to almost infinitesimal odds.

Comment: If it's not hard to expand VPN subnet later as-needed with wireguard, then I think it does make sense to just start with a /24. @FrankThomas - thanks for the heads up about the footgun. I'm definitely a dangerous amateur when it comes to networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use any netmask that you want in your internal network,
since the only users are local and behind the router.

You should verify that the same netmask is used by all devices,
including by the router.

The netmask `/24` is used by convention, since this is what
most routers will use by default. The router returns it
with the other parameters when it handles the DHCP request
issued when the devices are turned on (boot).

This netmask means that there are at most 253 devices in the
local network, which is more than enough for most households.